# What is the simplest way to split this string using PHP?

Tags: php

I have the below string in PHP.

```
:guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP
```

I need to create these variables from the string:

```
$nick = guest
$user = lbjpewueqi
$host = AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP
```

What is the best function to use to do this?

Ideally I would like to create some sort of function so I can pass to it the string and what part I want returned.

**For example:**

```
$string = "guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP";

echo stringToPart($string, nick);
guest

echo stringToPart($string, nick);
lbjpewueqi

echo stringToPart($string, host);
AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP
```

Comment: Have a look at `preg_split()`, You could look at the explode() function, you would need to use it 3 times though. On a side note, it usually helps get a faster response if you post an example of what you've tried and what errors/problems you've come across.

Comment: You probably don't just have to split *that* string, right? You'll have to split many different strings, which all share some common formatting rules. **Explain those rules.** Without it we can only guess at a solution which may or may not actually help you. The best thing to do is probably to make a regex *match* (not split): `if ($match = preg_match('???', $string)) echo $match[1]; ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version:

```
function stringToPart($string, $part) {
    if (preg_match('/^:(.*)!(.*)@(.*)/', $string, $matches)) {
        $nick = $matches[1];
        $user = $matches[2];
        $host = $matches[3];
        return isset($$part) ? $$part : null;
    }
}
```

More strict than preg_split solutions - it checks separators order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I accepted it. I'm using it like `stringToPart($something, nick);` but I get `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant nick - assumed 'nick'`. I'm using it right?

Comment: yes $part argument is a string and you have to declare strings using " or '. f.e. 'nick' or "nick"

Comment: Ah, I missed the ' by mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code may helpful for you

```
$p = '/[:!@]/';
$s = ":guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP";
print_r( preg_split( $p, $s ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should do what you're looking for.

```
$pattern = "/[:!@]/";
$subject = ":guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP";
print_r(preg_split($pattern, $subject));
```

The pattern is specifying what characters to split on so you could in theory have any amount of characters here if there were other instance you needed to account for different strings being passed in.

To return the values instead of just printing then to the screen use this:

```
$pattern = "/[:!@]/";
$subject = ":guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP";
$result = preg_split($pattern, $subject));

$nick = $result[1];
$user = $result[2];
$host = $result[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function like this:

```
$s = ":guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP";

function stringToPart($str, $part) {
    $pat['nick'] = '/:(.*)!/';
    $pat['user'] = '/.*!(.*)@/';
    $pat['host'] = '/@(.*)/';

    preg_match($pat[$part], $str, $m);
    if (count($m) > 1) return $m[1];
    return null;
}

echo stringToPart($s,'nick')."\n";
echo stringToPart($s,'user')."\n";
echo stringToPart($s,'host')."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringToPart(':guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP','nick');

function stringToPart($string, $type){   
    $result['nick']= substr($string,strpos($string,':')+1,(strpos($string,'!')-strpos($string,':')-1));
    $result['user']= substr($string,strpos($string,'!')+1,(strpos($string,'@')-strpos($string,'!')-1));
    $result['host']= substr($string,strpos($string,'@')+1);
    return $result[$type];        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function stringToPart($string, $key)
{
    $matches = null;
    $returnValue = preg_match('/:(?P<nick>[^!]*)!(?P<user>.*?)@(?P<host>.*)/', $string, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[$key]))
    {
        return $matches[$key];
    } else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

$string = ':guest!lbjpewueqi@AF8A326D.E0B4A40D.F85DC93A.IP';
echo stringToPart($string, "nick");
echo "<br />";

echo stringToPart($string, "user");
echo "<br />";

echo stringToPart($string, "host");
echo "<br />";
?>
```